# Infopath form code : get folder in which a web-enabled form is stored

Tags: sharepoint, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services, sharepoint-object-model

I have a web-enabled Infopath form stored in a document set.

Is is possible, in c# code inside the form, to get the folder (document set) inside of which the actual form is stored ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query parameter XSNLocation from query string...and for that you can refer to following blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/02/26/passing-data-into-a-form-input-parameters.aspx